# Broadcast receiver registered programmatically is being called even when the app is closed

Tags: android

I have a broadcast receiver for `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` that gets registered when my app is opened because of some local network stuff my app does. The broadcast receiver should run for as long as the app is running.

The user then goes on to other apps to do other things, my app might still be doing local network work but eventually it might get killed, which is ok. But then at some point that broadcast receiver called again.

What is odd to me is that I only register that broadcast receiver programmatically, it is not declared on my `AndroidManifest.xml`. Does Android not remove the receiver when it kills my app?

Is there some way for me to tell Android to clear all my receivers if the app is killed?

Comment: "But then at some point that broadcast receiver called again" -- if your process is running, and you have a registered receiver, that receiver can receive broadcasts. "Does Android not remove the receiver when it kills my app?" -- we do not know your definition of "kills my app".

Comment: I'm assuming my app was killed at some point because I have a Crashlytics log for `onCreate` of my `Application` class. So on the logs I see `onCreate()` called and less than a second later the `NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` broadcast is called. Nothing else that would trigger an app start is called, no `Activity` is started. So I can only assume that the broadcast is what is starting the app. Is there maybe a way to know for sure what is trigger the `Application.onCreate()`?

Comment: "So I can only assume that the broadcast is what is starting the app" -- only if you have a manifest-registered receiver, or you happen to register that receiver on app startup and the app was started for other reasons. "Is there maybe a way to know for sure what is trigger the `Application.onCreate()`?" -- if you can reproduce the behavior in "the lab", Logcat usually has system log entries around process starts that would give you some clues. For example, perhaps you registered a sticky service, or a `PendingIntent` that you registered with something was executed.

Comment: After reading more and more logs I suspect you are right and the receiver is just getting registered super quick and getting triggered. Unfortunately I haven't found a way to reproduce this issue myself, I've only seen it with real users on crashlytics. Looks like now I have to figure out a way to find out what is making the app start that isn't the main `Activity`. Thanks for the help.